# How to attach a token with blazor frontend http request

Tags: api, asp.net-core, blazor

I use blazor as frontend , api has completed with JWT configuration.
Frontend can create user account and login to API, but now my frontend httpclient is not setting with JWT token, so if I set [Authorised] in Api controller, Frontend can not access it.

The api program code is below

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DBContext>();//add user model,role model and connect toDbcontext
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options => {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Issuer"],
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Audience"],
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Authentication:SecretKey"]))
        };
    });
```

and contorller code is below

```
   [HttpGet("all")]
    [HttpHead]
    //[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Quiz>>> GetQuizzesDetailsAsync() {
     
       var quizzes= await _quizzesRepository.GetQuizzesDetailsAsync( );
        var quizDtos=_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<QuizOverviewDto>>(quizzes);
        return Ok(quizDtos);
    }
```

the frontend blazor program code is below

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IQuizService, QuizService>(
      client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7172"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

and "CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler" code is below.

```
public class CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler {
    public CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider,
        NavigationManager navigationManager)
        : base(provider, navigationManager) {
        ConfigureHandler(
           authorizedUrls: new[] { "https://localhost:7172" });

    }
}
```

}

access service is below

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<QuizOverviewDto>> GetQuizzesDetailsAsync() {         
            return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<QuizOverviewDto>>(
await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync("api/quizzes/all"),
new JsonSerializerOptions {
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
});
        }
```

now When I call GetQuizzesDetailsAsync() this service , it give me an error below.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider'
> while attempting to activate
> 'PerfectPoliciesFE.CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler'.
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider'
> while attempting to activate
> 'PerfectPoliciesFE.CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler'.    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type
> implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[]
> parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache
> lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain
> callSiteChain)

What the problem in my code? I think I only attach the logined user's token to http request, and it can access successfully, is any simple way to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Blazor WebAssembly, you need to inject the `IAccessTokenProvider` from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication` namespace inside your service and get the token from there. Once you have the token, you can pass the token value to the Authorization header of your httpclient.

```
private readonly IAccessTokenProvider _tokenProvider;
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

public class QuizService(IAccessTokenProvider tokenProvider, HttpClient httpClient)
{
    _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    _httpClient = httpClient;
}

private async Task RequestAuthToken()
{
    var requestToken = await _tokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();
    requestToken.TryGetToken(out var token);
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Value);
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<QuizOverviewDto>> GetQuizzesDetailsAsync() 
{  
  await RequestAuthToken();
  return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<QuizOverviewDto>>(
    await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync("api/quizzes/all"),
    new JsonSerializerOptions {
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
    });
 }
```

Comment: Hi Raffy, Thanks for your answer, but I use your code, its still not work, it display error.  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider' while attempting to activate 'PerfectPoliciesFE.Services.QuizService'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider' while attempting to activate

Comment: @JoshDing have you downloaded the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication` or `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly` package?

Comment: Hi Raffy, yes, I have using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, if not using it ,it will give me an error.

Comment: @JoshDing try removing the `CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler` and just use `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler` The problem is that the DI container can't find the `IAccessTokenProvider` hence it's throwing such error. The DI setup is done on the  `Program.cs` so check the config in there if the same error still persists.

Comment: Hi Raffy, what's BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHand used for, I use your code like this, and it is working, but I can not inject it into builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IQuizService, QuizService>(client => client.BaseAddress = new uri("https://localhost:7172")).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();builder.Services.AddHttpClient("API",client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7172")).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
    .CreateClient("API"));

Comment: @JoshDing basically the `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler` is the default delegating handler used to handle your outgoing http requests. You don't need to setup the `IHttpClientFactory` since is automatically handled if you use the AddHttpClient middleware. Just set the BaseUri and use the `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler` and you're good to go.

Comment: @JoshDing you can mark this as the answer if the solution works for you

Comment: Hi Raffy,  can I ask, what is this statement for ,builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });    should I set Api address in builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(lochalhost:7172) });

Comment: @JoshDing no you don't need to add this -> `builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });` It's the older way of adding an httpclient. Instead use the [AddHttpClient middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in creating your httpclients as advised by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to need CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler.

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<QuizService>(
      client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7172"))
        .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<AuthorizationMessageHandler>()
        .ConfigureHandler(
            authorizedUrls: new[] { "https://localhost:7172" }));
```

see [Configure the HttpClient handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-the-httpclient-handler-1)