# how to add a token head to a request using HttpClient from IHttpClientFactory in Blazor

Tags: jwt, blazor, token

I am trying to use JWT in my API, and configuration is completed, can use postman tool to access data from it. However when I use Blazor as front end to access it , the request doesn't have token, so always give a 401 code.

Below is my Blazor code.

program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IOptionService, OptionService> ("OptionAPI", (sp, cl) => {
    cl.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7172");
});
builder.Services.AddScoped(
    sp => sp.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("OptionAPI"));
```

OptionService.cs

```
    public class OptionService : IOptionService {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        public OptionService(HttpClient httpClient) {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }
        public async Task<IEnumerable<OptionOutputDto>> GetOptionsAsync(Guid quizId, Guid questionId) {           
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
                         = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "token");
            return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<OptionOutputDto>>(
await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync($"api/quizzes/{quizId}/{questionId}/options"),
new JsonSerializerOptions {
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
});
        }
```

I tired use " `new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "token");`" to attach token in header, but its not working, still give 401 code.

And I also tried use

```
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClient;
        public OptionService(IHttpClientFactory httpClient) {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }
        public async Task<IEnumerable<OptionOutputDto>> GetOptionsAsync(Guid quizId, Guid questionId) {
            var newHttpClient = _httpClient.CreateClient();
            newHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
                         = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "token");
            return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<OptionOutputDto>>(
await newHttpClient.GetStreamAsync($"api/quizzes/{quizId}/{questionId}/options"),
new JsonSerializerOptions {
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
});
        }
```

it's also not working, give me an error,
Unhandled exception rendering component: A suitable constructor for type 'Services.OptionService' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and all parameters of a public constructor are either registered as services or passed as arguments. Also ensure no extraneous arguments are provided.
System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type .....

Can anyone has a simple way to attach token in request header?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I gave a similar answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71634020/how-to-attach-a-token-with-blazor-frontend-http-request/71635457#71635457) Basically you need to include the `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler` when defining your httpclients. If you're using a typed httpclient, you can inject the `IAccessTokenProvider` and get the token from there. Kinda like this:

```
public class MyHttpClient(IAccessTokenProvider tokenProvider, HttpClient httpClient)
{
    _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    _httpClient = httpClient;
}

private async Task RequestAuthToken()
{
    var requestToken = await _tokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();
    requestToken.TryGetToken(out var token);
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Value);
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<ReplyDto>> SendHttpRequest() 
{  
  await RequestAuthToken();
  return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<ReplyDto>>(
    await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync("api/getendpoint"),
    new JsonSerializerOptions {
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
    });
 }
```

Comment: Hi Raffy, I have changed my code, builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IOptionService, OptionService> ("OptionAPI", (sp, cl) => {
    cl.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7172");
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>(); ;          public OptionService(IAccessTokenProvider tokenProvider, HttpClient httpClient) {
            _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }   but when I call _httpClient.GetStreamAsync method, it give me : No service for type '.BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler' has been registered.

Comment: @JoshDing add this line at the top of your `Program.cs` file: `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;`

Comment: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication; it's already there. If I don't using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication; BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler will display can not be recognised.

Comment: Hi Raffy, I also used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-6.0 code, still give me same error, I used Typed HttpClient and single HttpCient in my code, single HttpCient can attach token in single razor page, but I have many methods in repository, I prefer to use Typed HttpClient in my repository class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the good option is :

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IOptionService, OptionService> ("OptionAPI", (sp, cl) => {
cl.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7172");
```

});

Could you check if the token is present in header or not?

Comment: no, it's not, it give me an error,No service for type '.BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler' has been registered, so IAccessTokenProvider is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is most likely related to how the OptionService is being registered in dependency injection. It either needs an empty constructor adding - and/or - you need to ensure that the constructor has all of its dependencies registered correctly in the ServicesCollection too.

The exception is quite explicit:

> Ensure the type is concrete and all parameters of a public constructor
> are either registered as services or passed as arguments. Also ensure
> no extraneous arguments are provided